# get only latest items for each id type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a collection of objects and i need to retreive the ones that were last created for the same type(similar ids). I tried the idea below from an other post but i do not get the expected result.
Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

```
void Main()
{
List<data_item> itemlist1= new List<data_item>();


itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=1,

   Creationdate = new DateTime(2001, 6, 1),
    Size=28373

})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=2,

   Creationdate = new DateTime(1992, 6, 1),
    Size=2000

})
;

itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=2,


    Creationdate = new DateTime(2002, 6, 1),
     Size=300
})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=1,


   Creationdate = new DateTime(2005, 6, 1),
   Size =400
})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=3,


  Creationdate = new DateTime(1999, 6, 1),
  Size =10000
})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=3,


  Creationdate = new DateTime(2003, 6, 1),
  Size =5000
})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=3,


  Creationdate = new DateTime(1999, 4, 1),
  Size=3000
})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=5,


  Creationdate = new DateTime(1999, 6, 5),
  Size=230
})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=4,

  Creationdate = new DateTime(1999, 6, 1),
  Size =8700
})
;
itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
{
 id=5,


  Creationdate = new DateTime(1991, 6, 1),
  Size =6000
})
;

itemlist1.Dump();



var result = from t in itemlist1 group t by new UserQuery.data_item 
{ id=t.id,
Creationdate=t.Creationdate
} into gt

select gt.OrderByDescending(d=>d.Creationdate).First();

result.Distinct().Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class data_item
{
 public int id {get;set;}

 public DateTime Creationdate {get;set;}
 public int? Size {get;set;}



 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
var group = itemlist1.GroupBy(x=>x.id); // grouped by id
var newList = 
      group.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(y => y.Creationdate).First());
```

it will get most recent items for all ids, by grouping them by ID and then taking only most recent ones from that list and selecting to new list

`OrderByDescending` is ordering by date descending so `First` is taking most recent date. `Select` is selecting expression result to new list, so there should be a list of most recent items for all id's groups

Comment: This is a very elegant solution to my problem. Thousand thanks!

Comment: I just did. I hope my vote is reflected on the post.

Comment: How do i up-vote this? Sorry i'm not so familiar with this tool. Could you kindly let me know?

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp read this please http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow